# Five numbers at the points of a star

Tags: logical-deduction

I have a calendar with daily puzzles, and I want to verify something, so here is today's puzzle. I answered it myself and have the "official" answer as well. Please be sure to clearly state your reasoning for your answer.

Determine the number from 1 to 10 that goes at each point on this star according to the rules below.

[image: Going clockwise from the top of the star, the points are A, C, E, D, B. Apologies for the manual illustration instead of a nice digital version.]

1. The sum of all five numbers is 28, and no number is duplicated.
2. Consecutive numbers may not appear (a) at adjacent points nor (b) across a straight line from each other.
3. Point A is (a) greater than the sum of B and C and (b) less than the sum of D and E.
4. Points C and D sum to 11, and neither point is 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I've read/interpreted correctly, the following should work

> A = 6
>  B = 1
>  C = 3
>  D = 8
>  E = 10

My reasoning was more or less:

> **Lemma 1**: we can't have consecutive numbers *at all* with rule 2,
>
>  Possible pairs for C and D are $(1,10)$, $(2,9)$, $(3,8)$, $(4,7)$, and $(5,6)$, but $(1,10)$ isn't possible because of rule 4, $(5,6)$ is impossible by lemma 1, and $(2,9)$ and $(4,7)$ aren't possible because then we can no longer choose 5 numbers with no two pairwise points being consecutive numbers, leaving us with C and D being 3 and 8.
>
>  Now we need a sum of 17 with 3 numbers from the set $\{1,5,6,10\}$, which obviously leaves us with 1, 6, and 10 for A, B, and E.
>
>  The arrangement was then straightforward, though as Wesley pointed out, swapping A and E works as well

Comment: I agree that it should work, but I'd like to see exactly how you got there. I believe this to be one of two answers.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I think you could switch the values for A and E and it would still work.

Comment: I just ran a brute force script, switching A and E gives the only other possible configuration.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with:

> A = 10
>  B = 1
>  C = 3
>  D = 8
>  E = 6

Basically figuring:

> There can't be any consecutive numbers
>  Can't be 1 3 5 7 9
>  So need 10
>  And also 8
>  Then 6 3 1
>  Made the points fit the other criteria

Comment: Thanks! This was the "official" answer. Good to see both up here as confirmation.

Comment: @Allevu Yes, now see Will's answer works fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

> There can be no consecutive numbers, so we could take the first odd numbers and add 3 to them in total, obtaining 28. Even then, two of the numbers would end up being 1 and 3. If $a + b + c + d + e = 28$, $c + d = 11$ and $d + e > a > b + c$, then $11-c + e > a > b + c$. The expression $11-c + e$ must be greater than 10, and since $e-c > 1$, it's at least 13. $a, c, d$ and $e$ > 1, so $b=1$. $a, e$ and at least one of $c$ or $d$ are greater than 3, therefore the one left out equals 11-3=8. According to the "no consecutives" rule, $a+e$ can only be written as 10+6. Since $b + c$ must be less than 9...

The solution:

> $b=1, c=3, d=8$. $a$ and $e$ can either be 6 or 10.